# Prove that Ideal of the polynomials with even coefficients is maximal.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

$Z[x]$ is a ring. $I$ is an ideal of polynomials with even coefficients. Need to prove it is maxximal.

So I take another ideal $J$ and I know there is in J a polynomial with at least one odd coefficient. And because J is an ideal, it is closed under substraction, so I can take a similiar polynomial that in I (and therefore it will be from J eather), with coefficient bigger by 1 (and of course even) of the odd coeficient in the polynomial who is in J, but not in I.

Now by substraction of that two polinomials, I'll get $x^{i}\in J$. What I really want to show is that $1\in J$. Now can I say that in $x^{-i}\in Z[x]$
and therefore $x^{i}*x^{-i}\in J$ ? 
If not, how from the fact that there is polynomial in J with at least one odd coefficient, I can conclude that $1\in J$ or $J=R$?

Comment: But it is not maximal. For example the ideal $(2,x)$ strictly contains it and is not the entire ring.

Comment: Can you intepritate what does the brackets mean here? 
As I understand an ideal can be written as $<$polinomyal$>$ or as $\{h(x)\in I |$condition$\}$

Comment: I mean the ideal generated by the two elements $2$ and $x$, so you may have seen it as $\langle 2,x\rangle$ instead.

Comment: Ok, but $<(2,x)>$ in our case is I itself, isn't it ? The polynomials with even coefficients.

Comment: No, the polynomial $x$ is in $\langle 2,x\rangle$ but it certainly does not have even coefficients.

Comment: Yes, now I see. But how did you see it from the first place? 
Can you see it from the direction I tried? 
Maybe because by substraction of the polynomials that I get by the conditions on J and I, I don't get 1 as I want, but only $x$ in some degree, I can look at the creator of it, who is $x$ and at the creator of even number (and particullary the coefficients), and that's how to see in an intellegent guess, that it isn't maximal. 
I don't have any intuition for maximal ideal.

Comment: I did not as such "see" it this time, as I have seen these ideals so many times that I already know which are maximal.